# Snowflake returns 'invalid query block' error when using `=ANY()` subquery operator

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to filter a table with a list of strings as a parameter, but as I want to make the parameter optional (in Python sql user case) I can't use **IN** operator.

With postgresql I was able to build the query like this:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE (id = ANY(ARRAY[%(param_id)s]::INT[]) OR %(param_id)s IS NULL)
        ;
```

Then in Python one could choose to pass a list of `param_id` or just `None`, which will return all results from table1. E.g.
`pandas.read_sql(query, con=con, params={param_id: [id_list or None]})`

However I couldn't do the same with snowflake because even the following query fails:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE id = ANY(param_id)
        ;
```

Does Snowflake not have ANY operator? Because it is in their doc.

Comment: ANY is a subquery operator (a query within another query). You might also probably use [LIKE ANY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any.html) or [ILIKE ANY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ilike_any.html), depending how the string looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter is a single string literal `1,2,3` then it first needs to be parsed to multiple rows [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT s.value
             FROM TABLE (SPLIT_TO_TABLE(%(param_id)s, ',')) AS s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Yuya. This is not very clear in documentation. As per [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-subquery.html#id5) -
"IN is shorthand for = ANY, and is subject to the same restrictions as ANY subqueries."

However, it does not work this way - IN works with a IN list where as ANY only works with subquery.

Example -

```
select * from values (1,2),(2,3),(4,5);
+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
|---------+---------|
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       3 |
|       4 |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

IN works fine with list of literals -

```
select * from values (1,2),(2,3),(4,5) where column1 in (1,2);
+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
|---------+---------|
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       3 |
+---------+---------+
```

Below gives error (though as per doc IN and = ANY are same) -

```
select * from values (1,2),(2,3),(4,5) where column1 = ANY (1,2);
002076 (42601): SQL compilation error:
Invalid query block: (.
```

Using subquery ANY runs fine -

```
select * from values (1,2),(2,3),(4,5) where column1 = ANY (select column1 from values (1),(2));
+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
|---------+---------|
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       3 |
+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not make more sense for  both snowflake and postgresql to have two functions/store procedures that have one/two parameters.

Then the one with the “default” just dose not asked this fake question (is in/any some none) and is simpler. Albeit it you question is interesting.